# how to change the created by <user> in log to OdooBot when creating a record using odoo external API

Tags: odoo

I'm trying to create a new lead from external landing page

The code work as expected so far on Odoo 13.0+e-20200524

```
url = ODOO_URL
db = ODOO_DB
username = ODOO_USERNAME
password = ODOO_PASSWORD

kwargs = {
    'name': 'hello world',
}

common = xmlrpc.client.ServerProxy('{}/xmlrpc/2/common'.format(url))
uid = common.authenticate(db, username, password, {})
print(uid)

models = xmlrpc.client.ServerProxy('{}/xmlrpc/2/object'.format(url))

id = models.execute_kw(db, uid, password, 'crm.lead', 'create', [{
    'name': kwargs.get('name'),
    'user_id': 1,
}])

print(id)
```

But the log of the lead showing that my user created that lead (which is properly right)

[Change the created user to OdooBot in the view - screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2sjdV.png)

My question is:

How can I change the created user to OdooBot instead of my user?

PS: I already searched around and tried bellow parameters without luck:

```
'user_login': "OdooBot",
'create_uid': [1],
'write_uid': [1],
```

Comment: i cant see what version odo you are using ?

Comment: Sorry, I already edited my question with My Odoo Version `Odoo 13.0+e-20200524`

Answer (score 0):

`uid` represent a key role of User to create a record using xmlrpc.

You can change `uid` and it will log with that User.

Comment: - When I add `uid` to the `execute_kw` function, it raise <Fault 3: 'Access denied'>
- When I tried to change the `uid` in the parameter 
`...'user_id': 1, 'uid': 1`
 it raises `ValueError: Invalid field 'uid' on model 'crm.lead'

Comment: You need to change user login,password and assign it to uid variable. According to error, user validation failed.

Comment: I think you misunderstand me. Yes I know Odoo will log the user which I use its username/password to execute the API request. But I'm looking for a way to log it as `OdooBot` because it an automated tasks